# Image Overlap in XAML Grid in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, windows-store-apps

I wanted to see if someone could point me in the right direction.  I'm wanting to create a basic card game app for the Windows Store.  I have done multiple apps already, and I am pretty familiar with XAML grids and placing images within cells.  In the card game, I am going to have a very similar setup to Microsoft's Hearts game (with cards ranked at the bottom and the cards overlapping each other).  My problem is that I don't know how to make images in the grid cells overlap each other.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?  Thanks.

BTW, if the solution requires code behind I know VB.Net and C#.

Comment: have you try to set the Canvas.ZIndex of images? if Canvas.ZIndex of ImageA is big than ImageB. ImageA will overlap ImageB.

Comment: If you want to make images one by one above , you can set different margins for each image from bottom to top. Can't you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan`.

For Example:

Consider a 3x3 `Grid` (empty cells denoted with `X`):

```
X X X
X X X
X X X
```

Now consider an element with `Grid.Row=0` and `Grid.Column=1`. It will be rendered like this (the `O` is a filled cell).

```
X O X
X X X
X X X
```

Now, if we increased that element's `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan`, but keep its `Row` and `Column` positions the same, we are creating a larger box with a top-left cell at the same position. Consider `Grid.RowSpan=2` and `Grid.ColumnSpan=2`.

```
X O O
X O O
X X X
```

The "box" is anchored in the position `1,0` (x,y or column,row), but extends out to the next cells, making a 2x2 sub-grid.

Now, consider a second element `Y`. If we were to take the previous drawing and add `Y` with `Grid.Row=1, Grid.Column=0, Grid.RowSpan=2, Grid.ColumnSpan=3`, then we would get:

```
X O O
Y Y Y
Y Y Y
```

Remember that the Canvas is a "Stack" in that the last-drawn object is on top.

You can use this method to overlap different elements in a grid. One last example, as it will illustrate better the card overlap concept you're likely looking for.

```
O := 
{
    Grid.Row=0, 
    Grid.Column=0, 
    Grid.RowSpan=2,
    Grid.ColumnSpan=2
}

Y := 
{
    Grid.Row=1, 
    Grid.Column=1, 
    Grid.RowSpan=2,
    Grid.ColumnSpan=2
}
```

Drawing O first, then Y Results in

```
O O X
O Y Y
X Y Y
```

Drawing Y first, then O results in

```
O O X
O O Y
X Y Y
```

You can also modify the Canvas.ZIndex manually, I believe, as @ChrisShao mentioned.

Comment: Im attempting to make a card game as well. Is there any advantage to use this over margin?